# The requested URL / was not found on this server., django openshift

Tags: django, openshift

[image]

I am trying to set up a Django 1.7 project to push to openshift. I'm following https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17. I've sucessfully got the initial project going locally, now I'm trying to move a local project into this file structure so I can deploy it.

I can run the project fine locally. After pushing to openshift I see:

```
remote: Starting Python 2.7 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
remote: Application directory "wsgi/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION ENV VAR detected
remote: Application "mysite/wsgi.py" selected as default WSGI entry point
remote: --> ACTION HOOK: post_deploy <--
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://54***00003f@***-***.rhcloud.com/~/git/**.git/
   0a488d3..5af95ee  master -> master
```

mysite.urls.py contains:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^index/', 'app1.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'app1.views.contact', name='contact'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

mysite.views contains:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class Index(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('django 1.7 on Openshift')
```

When I open the openshift url , I get!:

```
Not Found . The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

The templates are all in the templates folder (in the screenshot). I copied it over from under the static root.

How can get the project working on openshift deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill, do you have your repo for this hosted on github?  if so, paste the link here and i can go over all the files to find your issue.

If not, please post your URLs.py an dViews.py

Did you get the base repo working first, before adding anything you wanted changed?  Meaning, follow my instructions to the letter on the repo, get it running locally and then on OS?

I've had several questions / issues when people don't run the base install first, and then add their logic.

Comment: Hi John, I've made some changes above and added the question to your github repo . I don't have my version hosted on github.

Comment: Hi John, thanks again for your help on this . After your fixes, people can use my repo at https://github.com/kc1/s1 as an example of how to deploy a website using your approach. Happy holidays - Bill